# gmap3 offsetting map center

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I have a map with an infobox overlay on the top of the marker. As the box is quote big it goes out the view so I need to offset the center of the map about 150px down. 
I can't figure out how to use the panBy method to offset the map center using gmap3 jQuery plugin.

This is my code:

```
var center = [<?php echo $coordinate ?>];
$('#sw-map')
  .gmap3({
    center: center,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  })
  .marker({
    position: center
  })
  .overlay({
    position: center,
    content:  html,
    x:-125,
    y:-260
  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution myself.
Forgot to mention i was using gmap3 v7.2, i had to switch back to v6 changing the code a little bit, here's the working solution:

```
var center = [<?php echo $coordinate ?>];
var default_zoom = <?php echo $sw_single_map_default_zoom_level ?>;
var max_zoom = <?php echo $sw_single_map_max_zoom_level ?>;
var min_zoom = <?php echo $sw_single_map_min_zoom_level ?>;

var offsetX = -125;
var offsetY = -268;
var panY    = -100;

<?php if ($sw_single_map_infobox == 1) {
    ?>
var offsetX = -47;
var offsetY = -154;
var panY    = -70;
<?php } ?>

$("#sw-map").gmap3({ 
    map:{
        options:{
          center: center,
          zoom: default_zoom,
          maxZoom: max_zoom,
          minZoom: min_zoom,
          mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
      },
      marker:{
        latLng: center
      },
      overlay:{
        latLng: center,
        options:{
          content: html,
          offset:{
            x: offsetX,
            y: offsetY
          }
        }
      }
    });

var map = $("#sw-map").gmap3("get");
map.panBy(0,panY);
```